# JQUERY refill while emptying

Tags: javascript, jquery, caching, fadein, fadeout

I'm trying to smoothly reload this div.
`

`grabchart(userid, div);`
purpose is to fill the div with users data.

```
$( ".reload" ).click(function() {
    if($("#line-example-refresh").is(':empty') && ($("#line-example:not(empty)"))) {
            $( "#line-example" ).empty();
            <?php echo 'grabchart('.$_COOKIE['uid'].',"line-example-refresh");';?> 
    }

    if($("#line-example").is(':empty') && ($("#line-example-refresh:not(empty)"))) {

            <?php echo 'grabchart('.$_COOKIE['uid'].',"line-example");';?> 
            $( "#line-example-refresh" ).empty();
    }
});
```

What's happening here is that my script verify the first statement and then clear #line-example,
then since it just cleared this div, it makes the second statement true.
What i need is verify if one of twos statement is true then halt the script.

Comment: So add the data and call fadeIn? Not sure how PHP cpde in JavaScript is supposed to work... Hopefully you know that PHP only runs when the page is rendered.

Comment: not clear what you are asking. Cache what? More dynamic than what?

Answer (score 0):

Else if's forcing the script to "chose" between one of the two statements.

```
$( ".reload" ).click(function() {
    if($("#line-example-refresh").is(':empty') && ($("#line-example:not(empty)"))) {
            $( "#line-example" ).empty();
            <?php echo 'grabchart('.$_COOKIE['uid'].',"line-example-refresh");';?> 
    }

    else if($("#line-example").is(':empty') && ($("#line-example-refresh:not(empty)"))) {

            <?php echo 'grabchart('.$_COOKIE['uid'].',"line-example");';?> 
            $( "#line-example-refresh" ).empty();
    }
});
```